# About RESTful web service

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I used to prictice to write a RESTful webservice,but when i finished it,i found i can`t test it by using RESTClient.

My code is like this:

```
      //-------------------------
      @POST
      @Path("add")
      @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
      @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
      public String addCategory(Category category) {
          System.out.println("处理添加类别逻辑，接受的数据为id:" + category.getId()
            + ",name:" + category.getName());
          return "ok";
      }

      //-------------------------
      @XmlRootElement
      public class Category {
      private int id;
      private String name;
      public Category(){}
      public Category(int id, String name){
          this.id = id;
          this.name = name;
      }
      these are getter and setters
      ...
      //---------------------
```

What`s more, I sent a POST HTTP who`s body is

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
      <category>
         <id>1</id>
         <name>No.1 category</name>
      </category>aaa
```

But i got a "HTTP Status 415 - Unsupported Media Type".

So,what i can do to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you send HTTP POST, set explicitly the header `"Content-Type: application/xml"`, this should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You RESTful service accepts the following Mime types (MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), you need to set the Content Type header i.e.

> Content-Type:application/xml; charset=UTF-8

If you are using Chrome to test your RESTful service then the [Advanced Rest Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo/related) is a good plugin to use, it has a content type drop down where you can choose from popular ones or add your own. I'm sure there are similar plugins for Firefox

Comment: In this particular case the author is sending XML, so application/json won't be correct.